# Предсказание погоды с памятью

Tags: python

Самый простой случай в статистике — это когда нужно определить вероятность появления одного из равновероятных событий. Например, выпадения орла или решки при броске монеты. Если бросать монету несколько раз, то вероятность не изменится, монета ничего не знает о результатах наших предыдущих экспериментов.
Но так бывает не всегда. Замечено, что после пасмурного дня скорее всего будет тоже пасмурный, а после ясного — ясный. Допустим, что мы много лет наблюдали за погодой и накопили большой объем статистики и определили вероятность ясного дня после ясного как p, соответственно, пасмурного после ясного как 1 — p; пасмурного после пасмурного как q, тогда ясного после пасмурного 1 — q.
Мы хотим узнать, с какой вероятностью через несколько дней будет определенная погода. Пусть сегодня ясно. Тогда завтра ясно будет с вероятностью p, а пасмурно — 1 — p. А послезавтра?

Остается только определить максимальную вероятность интересующей нас погоды из полученных. Так можно попытаться предсказать погоду на любой день после сегодняшнего. Напишите для этого программу.

Формат ввода
Строка — какая погода сегодня.
Вещественное число — вероятность ясного дня после ясного.
Вещественное число — вероятность пасмурного дня после пасмурного.
Целое число — через сколько дней нам нужен прогноз.

Формат вывода
Вывести прогноз на интересующий нас день — ясно или пасмурно, а также полученную вероятность. Если вероятность одинакова, вывести — равновероятно.

Пример 1

Ввод
ясно
0.9
0.75
2

Вывод
ясно
0.81

Пример 2

Ввод
пасмурно
0.6
0.4
3

Вывод
ясно
0.216

Пример 3

Ввод
пасмурно
0.5
0.5
3

Вывод
равновероятно
0.125

Есть код, но он выводит не много другие числа

```
if input() == 'ясно':
    cur = [1.0, 0.0]
else:
    cur = [0.0, 1.0]
prob = [float(input()), float(input())]
for i in range(int(input())):
    cur = [cur[0] * prob[0] + cur[1] * (1.0 - prob[1]), cur[1] * prob[1] + cur[0] * (1.0 - prob[0])]
if cur[0] > cur[1]:
    print('ясно', cur[0], sep='\n')
elif cur[1] > cur[0]:
    print('пасмурно', cur[1], sep='\n')
else:
    print('равновероятно')
```

Comment: В примере №2 ответ какой-то странный. Если там ясно с вероятностью 0.216 (меньше половины), то в этот день должно быть пасмурно же.

Comment: @GrAnd Да и в первом примере 0.81 = 0.9 * 0.9, т.е. рассматривается только вариант, что будет ясно-ясно-ясно, а вероятность варианта ясно-пасмурно-ясно во внимание не берётся вообще. Если же считать по формуле, получается чуть больше именно из-за учёта вероятности второго варианта развития событий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо ожидается какое-то такое решение:

```
def forecast(sunny, cloudy, days):
    if days == 0:
        if   sunny > cloudy: return (sunny,  'ясно')
        elif sunny < cloudy: return (cloudy, 'пасмурно')
        else:                return (sunny,  'равновероятно')
    return max(forecast(sunny * prob[0],   sunny * (1 - prob[0]), days-1),
               forecast(cloudy * (1 - prob[1]), cloudy * prob[1], days-1))

today = input()
prob = [float(input()), float(input())]
print(*forecast(today == "ясно", today == "пасмурно", int(input()))[::-1], sep="\n")
```

Посчитать вероятности переходов:

- ясно - ясно
- ясно - пасмурно
- пасмурно - ясно
- пасмурно - пасмурно

Получив новые вероятности, подсчитать то же самое для следующего дня. И т.д. В качестве результата взять максимальную вероятность.